# Travis not publishing to Bintray properly

Tags: travis-ci, bintray

I'm trying to publish a java lib to Bintray, and then using that lib in another project by defining the bintray repo in gradle.

This all works when deploying to Bintray from my local machine, but when I try to get it working from Travis CI it doesn't seem to publish properly.

When I try to add a dependency in a different gradle project it cannot find the artefact, even though I know where it is and that the files have been uploaded.

I have noticed that the `maven-metadata.xml` doesn't seem to be created properly when I use Travis, I was under the impression that Bintray would create it for me.

**.travis.yml**

```
language: java

before_install:
  - if [ -n "$TRAVIS_TAG" ]; then ./travis_prebuild.sh; fi

script:
  - echo "Building artifacts"
  - gradle clean build
  - if [ -n "$TRAVIS_TAG" ]; then gradle createPom; fi

before_deploy:
  - echo "Creating description file for bintray."
  - ./travis_postbuild.sh

deploy:
  provider: bintray
  file: "descriptor.json"
  user: $BINTRAY_USER
  key: $BINTRAY_API_KEY
  passphrase: $BINTRAY_GPG_PASSWORD
  skip_cleanup: true
  on:
    tags: true
```

**bintray-conf.json**

```
{
  "package": {
    "name": "core",
    "repo": "Qatja",
    "subject": "wetcat",
    "issue_tracker_url": "https://github.com/Qatja/core/issues",
    "vcs_url": "https://github.com/Qatja/core.git",
    "labels": ["MQTT", "Java"],
    "public_download_numbers": true,
    "public_stats": true
  },

  "version": {
    "name": "@VERSION@",
    "gpgSign": true
  },

  "files":
  [
    {"includePattern": "build/libs/(.*\.jar)", "uploadPattern": "@VERSION@/$1"},
    {"includePattern": "build/(.*\.pom)",  "uploadPattern": "@VERSION@/$1"}
  ],

  "publish": true
}
```

[Bintray repo](https://bintray.com/wetcat/Qatja/core)

[Github repo](https://github.com/Qatja/core)

Comment: I could never figure out why this didn't work, eventually I went with script deployment instead since that seemed to be the accepted way. [https://github.com/bintray/gradle-bintray-plugin](https://github.com/bintray/gradle-bintray-plugin)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to rename the "descriptor.json" to "bintray-conf.json". The rest looks pretty much the same as my working configuration.

```
deploy:
  provider: bintray
  file: ./bintray-conf.json
```